# Wifi signal but no connection callback iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, swift3, reachability

The scenario you are in an area of public open wifi hotspot . Your status bar shows the wifi icon which means it's getting the signal. However you are not connected until you visit the hotspot wifi providers landing page. 
 My application uses the internet and I would like to know when the wifi signal of the hotspot provider is being received (showing the wifi signal in the status bar) but not actually connected to the internet. As it is users have to open the safari application get the landing page. Connect to the hotspot. Return to my application. 
 What I would like is for my app to detect the need to connect and present a UIWebView which will show the landing page and log user into the hotspot within my app.

Any help on what callbacks or delegates I can explore to resolve this?

Comment: The best you can do is to try and retrieve a known piece of content from your server; if you don't get what you are expecting then you need to login

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but when you see Wi-Fi signal and not connected in application, phone automatically opens safari and visit hotspot wifi provider landing page. If this is not the case, you can check internet with a simple request or get help from

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

So after checking internet connection, you can show them a message, "No internet" or something like that. So they will go settings and try to solve it.

Comment: I use Reachability but that returns it has a connection when there is still the need to visit the providers landing page so doesn't work